# Crear imagen webP con fondo transparente

Tags: php, php7, imagen, gd

Colegas, como podría convertir un png con fondo transparente a formato webP sin que el fondo me lo vuelva blanco, tengo mi código de la siguiente manera:

```
        $typeImg = pathinfo($imageUploadPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        switch($typeImg){
            case 'jpeg':
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUploadPath);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($imageUploadPath);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $img = imagecreatefromgif($imageUploadPath);
                break;
            default:
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUploadPath);
        }

        imageAlphaBlending($img, false);
        imageSaveAlpha($img, true);

        $newName = str_replace($fileType, 'webp', $imageUploadPath);

        if(imagewebp($img, $newName, $quality)){
            $statusMsg = "(succes) La imagen se convirtió a webP satisfactoriamente.";
        } else {
            $statusMsg = "(fail) Lo sentimos, la imagen no logro convertirse a webP";
        }

        imagedestroy($img);
```

No le hayo, alguien podrá apoyarme?

Comment: ¿Que versión de PHP estas usando? ¿Estas seguro de que el fondo es blanco? Si abris una imagen WebP directamente en el navegador ves una cosa, pero si la incluis en un archivo HTML vas a ver otra.

Comment: @Marcos tienes toda la razón jaja, como olvide ese detalle, así es, si se muestra con transparencia en mi HTML, asunto resuelto, gracias por tu apoyo!